# How to make proof environment without amsthm?

Tags: amsthm

I want to submit a paper to [this Journal](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=ETS) and they want the author to use the [etds.cls](ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/etds-cls/).

The class uses a package called 'theorem' and they have scripted there own theorem command

```
 \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\setlength{\theorempreskipamount}{6pt plus 2pt}
\setlength{\theorempostskipamount}{6pt plus 2pt}

\begingroup \makeatletter
\gdef\th@plain{\normalfont\itshape
  \def\@begintheorem##1##2{%
        \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ {##2.}]}%
\def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
   \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)]}}
\endgroup
```

Therefore, I can not include the package amsthm because I will get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined.
```

However, I cannot use the proof environment if I do not include the amsthm package. I asked the Journal what they would recommend and they responded that I can include a proof environment with

```
\newcommand{\proof}{\noindent {\it Proof. }}
```

but how do I get the square at the end of the proof without using amsthm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy some definitions from `amsthm.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% from here-------------------------
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode % if math mode, assume display: omit penalty etc.
  \else \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \fi
  \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\newcommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont
  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@ \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
    #1.]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \qed\endtrivlist
}
\newcommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\makeatother
%% upto here----------------------------
\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    This is a proof
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

an even shorter approach, again stealing (or adapting) definitions from `amsthm.sty`.

```
\providecommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}
\newcommand{\mathqed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
```

then, if you don't really want to define a `proof` environment, you can simply use the
`\proof` command suggested by the journal staff (but *please* use `{\itshape ...}` or
`\textit{...}` instead of `\it`!), and end the theorem statement with

```
`\qed`
```

*without* leaving a blank line before it.  this will flush the box to the right margin
if it follows text, or place it a quad away from the end of the math expression if it's
at the end of a display.  you should also follow the proof by some extra space, say
`\medskip`.

(personal observation on the document class -- it's woefully out of date; the
documentation is dated 1999, and it wasn't even using "best practices" for that time.
i'd be ashamed to distribute it.)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty - much shorter than @HarishKumar s solution, possibly less robust, but perhaps sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newenvironment{proof}
{\textit{Proof:} }
{$\square$}

\begin{document}

Theorem: whatever

\begin{proof}
Here's why.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is ok, but could get orphaned from the theorem, and the final marker could also get oprhaned

Comment: Agreed, this is not a good solution (sadly seen quite a lot). Also the `\textit{Proof:}` part gets indented (in most cases)